# App crashes when trying to hide progress bar

Tags: javascript, java, database, firebase

When I run this code Apps crashes after loading the progress bar.With the code I was trying to display an image from firebase in a card view . Everthing worked fine until I add a code to hide progress bar after the image was completely loaded from database.

Please suggest some methods to be implemented in my code so that I can remove the progress bar when image is completely loaded from database

```
package com.example.ananthu.currentaffairs;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;




public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    private ProgressBar progressBar;



    private RecyclerView mPeopleRV;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<News, NewsActivity.NewsViewHolder> mPeopleRVAdapter;








    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pro);



        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



        setTitle("News");

        //"News" here will reflect what you have called your database in Firebase.
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("News");
        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);

        mPeopleRV = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecycleView);

        DatabaseReference personsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("News");
        Query personsQuery = personsRef.orderByKey();

        mPeopleRV.hasFixedSize();
        mPeopleRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions personsOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<News>().setQuery(personsQuery, News.class).build();

        mPeopleRVAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<News, NewsActivity.NewsViewHolder>(personsOptions) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(NewsActivity.NewsViewHolder holder, final int position, final News model) {

                holder.setImage(getBaseContext(), model.getImage());





                }



            @Override
            public NewsActivity.NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.news_row, parent, false);

                return new NewsActivity.NewsViewHolder(view);



            }
        };

        mPeopleRV.setAdapter(mPeopleRVAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mPeopleRVAdapter.startListening();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mPeopleRVAdapter.stopListening();




    }



    public static class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private ProgressBar progressBar;

        View mView;
        public NewsViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

        }


        public void setImage(Context ctx, String image){
            ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);

            Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image,new Callback() {
                @Override// This the place where problem occcurs
                public void onSuccess() {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {

                }
            });


        }



    }
}
[The image shows the Logcat when I run the code][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uP4n.png
```

Comment: Crashes with what error? Post the error with trace in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the progressbar in NewsViewHolder class not needed
you can use static progressbar like below code:

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import ir.pofelak.dialer.R;


public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    public static ProgressBar progressBar;



    private RecyclerView mPeopleRV;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<News, NewsActivity.NewsViewHolder> mPeopleRVAdapter;








    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pro);



        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



        setTitle("News");

        //"News" here will reflect what you have called your database in Firebase.
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("News");
        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);

        mPeopleRV = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecycleView);

        DatabaseReference personsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("News");
        Query personsQuery = personsRef.orderByKey();

        mPeopleRV.hasFixedSize();
        mPeopleRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions personsOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<News>().setQuery(personsQuery, News.class).build();

        mPeopleRVAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<News, NewsActivity.NewsViewHolder>(personsOptions) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(NewsActivity.NewsViewHolder holder, final int position, final News model) {

                holder.setImage(getBaseContext(), model.getImage());





            }



            @Override
            public NewsActivity.NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.news_row, parent, false);

                return new NewsActivity.NewsViewHolder(view);



            }
        };

        mPeopleRV.setAdapter(mPeopleRVAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mPeopleRVAdapter.startListening();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mPeopleRVAdapter.stopListening();




    }



    public static class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        View mView;
        public NewsViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

        }


        public void setImage(Context ctx, String image){
            ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);

            Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image,new Callback() {
                @Override// This the place where problem occcurs
                public void onSuccess() {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {

                }
            });


        }
```

Comment: edit the progress bar in NewsActivity class...set progress bar public static and remove         private ProgressBar progressBar; from NewsViewHolder Class

Comment: Thank you very much,it solves the problem :-)
can you explain me ,how it worked now

Comment: Your progressBar must be the same everywhere Because When you want to gone progressBar, you must gone the same progressBar that you previously visibled.(don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it worked for you)